# Returning Multiple Rows with MySqli and Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

For the past two days or so I've been converting my functions to mysqli. I've run into a problem. I have a function that returns an array containing a row from the database. However, I want the array to contain multiple rows versus one. Also, how would I be able to echo out the individual posts. Here is my failed attempt that only displays one row in the array.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");   

function display_posts ($mysqli, $user_id) {

   $fields = "`primary_id`, `poster_id`, `profile_user_id`, `post`";   

   $user_id = (int)$user_id;

   $query = "SELECT DISTINCT $fields FROM `posts` WHERE `profile_user_id` = $user_id 
   LIMIT 4";                    

   if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

   return $row;

   $result->free();

   $stmt->close();

}}
```

Here I am trying to display the data.

```
$user_id = 1;

$posts = display_posts($mysqli, $user_id);

//Not sure what to do with $posts. A While loop perhaps to display each post?
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use a loop to get them all at once:

```
<?php
function resultToArray($result) {
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
}

// Usage
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT $fields FROM `posts` WHERE `profile_user_id` = $user_id LIMIT 4';
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$rows = resultToArray($result);
var_dump($rows); // Array of rows
$result->free();
```

Comment: Although I was hoping to get an answer how to echo out each individual value I went ahead and figured it out myself. Thanks for the help nevertheless. I decided to take out the function `resultToArray` and append it to my original function.

Comment: Worst way to do it!!, why pass the work to PHP when MYSQL can do this by default. See my answer below.

Answer (score 14):

Why not use directly like this:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($mysqli->query($query), MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: @KateGregory there is nothing to explain actually. Beside the fact that this function is only available since 5.3 and only under mysqlnd.

Comment: Not much to explain. Rather than do a while cycle, use the available mysqli methods to get the entire set of results. Also avoiding to declare an extra function for it. And yes, it's >5.3 up. But as far as i know mysqli is also 5.3 and up

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but I believe this is what you wanted to achieve:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$fields = "`primary_id`, `poster_id`, `profile_user_id`, `post`";

function display_posts () {

    global $mysqli;
    global $fields;

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT $fields FROM `posts` WHERE `profile_user_id` = $user_id LIMIT 4";

    $posts = $mysqli -> query($query) or die('Error: '.$mysqli -> error);

    if ($posts -> num_rows > 0) {

        while ($row = $posts -> fetch_assoc()) {

        $value = $row['/*The table column here (You can repeat this line with a different variable e.g. $value 2, $value 3 etc and matching them with the respective table column)*/'];

        echo $value./*Concatenate the other variables ($value 1 etc) here*/'<br />';

        }

    }else {

        echo 'No records found.';

    }

}

//Call the function
display_posts ();
```

Comment: You don't want to make your $mysqli global. That's a huge security risk.