# Retreive Multiple Rows from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to retrieve multiple rows from my database but not using my `Primary key`.
Table structure is shown below :

[image]

`id` is the `primary key` of the table. 
`userid` is a `foreign key` which is the instances of the actual id that represent a user acct.
`data` and `someid`: are two columns who data i want to store in a variable and display it!

I tried this :

```
$data = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM user_pokemon_db WHERE id = '".$id."' "); 

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{ 
 $level = $rows['level']; 
 echo $level;
 $exp = $rows['exp']; 
  echo $exp;
}
```

But it shows only data of the first row and not all rows!

Comment: Provide post with your sql query

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't get it.. can u give some eg..

Comment: Without sql query help is not possible.

Comment: $data = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM user_pokemon_db WHERE id = '".$id."' ");

Comment: As a side note, you're probably wonderfully open to SQL Injection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning Multiple Rows with MySqli and Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272017/returning-multiple-rows-with-mysqli-and-arrays)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get all rows which have userid equals to 1 (i.e. first two rows.)
then you have change your query to this-

```
$data = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM user_pokemon_db WHERE userid = '".$user_id."' ");
```

$user_id is the variable containing the value of userid column.

In Your current query you are getting value of that row which has id=$id. since id is primary key ,So there is only one row corresponding to it.  so only first row is shown.