# for loop keep displaying first row data for all rows in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to display order list from database. i am using for loop for fetching data from the database. For loop keep displaying first row data for all rows in php. don't want to use whileloop because while loop skips first value so please anyone can help in for loop.
here is the code:

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET['order_id']; 
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Cannot Connect to the database!");
mysql_select_db("login",$link) or die ("Cannot select the database!");


 $query="SELECT * FROM ordered_product WHERE order_id='".$id."'"; 
 $resource=mysql_query($query,$link);
 $result=mysql_fetch_array($resource);
 $rows=mysql_num_rows($resource);

?>
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1" id="rcorners1" style="margin-left: 220px; margin-top: 10px;"  >

                                <font size="3" color="black">                               
                                <div id="newone">
                                <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                <?php


                                for ($i=0; $i < $rows ; $i++)
                                {         
                                ?>


                                <div>
                                <label >Product Code:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php  echo $result[2] ?>  </label>
                                </div>

                                <div >
                                <label >Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $result[3] ?></label>

                                </div>


                                <div>
                                <label >Quantity:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $result[5]?></label>

                                </div>


                                <div>
                                <label >Price:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $result[6] ?></label>
                                </div>


                                <?php
                                        }
                                 ?>                     

                                 </div>

                                <input name="deliver" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Deliver" />

                                <input name="back" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Back" onclick="window.location.href='orders.php'" />
```

Comment: Side note: I'm curious as to the status of your previous questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning Multiple Rows with MySqli and Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272017/returning-multiple-rows-with-mysqli-and-arrays)

Comment: Please upgrade to `MySQLi` or `PDO`. . The functions for `mysql_*` are deprecated in PHP 5 and removed in PHP 7.

Comment: you should use something like $result[i][2] to show data for that specific row and column

Answer (score 0):

you need to use foreach not for loop like this :

```
<?php

                        foreach ($list as $l){
                    ?>
            <tr>


                    <td><?php echo $l[0] ;?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $l[1] ;?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $l[2] ;?> </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, It may be because of $result has only one record. So we need to 
get all data into $result

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET['order_id']; 
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Cannot Connect to the database!");
mysql_select_db("login",$link) or die ("Cannot select the database!");


 $query="SELECT * FROM ordered_product WHERE order_id='".$id."'"; 
 $resource=mysql_query($query,$link);
// $result=mysql_fetch_array($resource);

$result = array();

while ($row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource))
    $result[] = $row_user;
}

 $rows=mysql_num_rows($resource);

?>
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1" id="rcorners1" style="margin-left: 220px; margin-top: 10px;"  >

                                <font size="3" color="black">                               
                                <div id="newone">
                                <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                <?php


                                for ($i=0; $i < $rows ; $i++)
                                {         
                                ?>


                                <div>
                                <label >Product Code:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php  echo $result[$i][2] ?>  </label>
                                </div>

                                <div >
                                <label >Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $result[$i][3] ?></label>

                                </div>


                                <div>
                                <label >Quantity:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $result[$i][5]?></label>

                                </div>


                                <div>
                                <label >Price:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $result[$i][6] ?></label>
                                </div>


                                <?php
                                        }
                                 ?>                     

                                 </div>

                                <input name="deliver" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Deliver" />

                                <input name="back" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Back" onclick="window.location.href='orders.php'" />
```

Comment: Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\order2.php on line 295  and 295 line is  <label >Product Code:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php  echo $result[$i][2] ?>  </label>

Comment: what is the output of $result , can u put print_r($result); and show me the output